# QComboBox in QItemDelegate to show only the portion corresponding to other column

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, qt

I have two MySQL tables with one-to-many relations.

Table `si`:

```
id integer primary key auto_increment,
...
cur_verify_date date,
...
```

Table `verify`:

```
...
si_id integer,  -- id in 'si'
verify_date date,
...
```

So I need a combobox delegate for a table `si` in `QTableView` to choose items of `verify_date` only with `si_id` for corresponding `id`, different items in each row. However, the delegates can have, as I suppose, only identical values for each row. Is there a way to do it in the way I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with `QItemDelegate`, I would say that's your main solution when you want to show combobox in `QTableView`.

Check is signature of `createEditor` method from `QAbstractItemDelegate`:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#createEditor

You can use `QModelIndex` parameter to define custom values for each row in your combobox.
While actual implementation will depend on your implementation of your model, you can check this simple example of that idea.

```
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class DummyModel : public QAbstractTableModel {
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        return 5;
    }
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        return 2;
    }
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const override
    {
        return __super::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override
    {
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole && index.column() == 0)
            return index.row();
        return {};
    }
};

class ComboBoxItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
public:
    ComboBoxItemDelegate(QObject* parent = nullptr)
        : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {};

    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const override
    {
        QComboBox* cb = new QComboBox(parent);
        //place to query database for actual values
        const auto value = index.model()->index(index.row(), 0).data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
        cb->addItem(value);
        cb->addItem(value);

        return cb;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  DummyModel model;

  QTableView table_view;
  table_view.setModel(&model);

  ComboBoxItemDelegate cb_delegate;
  table_view.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, &cb_delegate);

  table_view.show();
  return app.exec();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't imagine that the model might be accessed from QModelIndex  )